# What is the exact meaning of the data fields within FrameSystemAccountInfo?

Tags: pallet

For example:

```
  nonce: 88
  consumers: 3
  providers: 1
  sufficients: 0
  data: {
    free: 5,490,171,776,270,990,576,365,620
    reserved: 0
    miscFrozen: 366,590,800,018,553,095,998,081
    feeFrozen: 366,590,800,018,553,095,998,081
  }
}
```

I comprehend the `nonce` field, the `free balance` field, `feeFrozeen` field. However, I find the remaining fields to be unclear or difficult to understand

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the meaning of the account provider, sufficients and consumer?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/263/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-account-provider-sufficients-and-consumer)

Comment: What about `miscFrozen`? What is different `miscFrozen` and `feeFrozen`? I see `miscFrozen` and `feeFrozen` are always identical balance.

Comment: I've updated by answer.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the account reference counters, you can find more information at this link: [What is the meaning of the account provider, sufficients and consumer?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/263/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-account-provider-sufficients-and-consumer).

---

> https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_support/traits/tokens/struct.WithdrawReasons.html

In addition to the frozen types `misc_frozen` and `fee_frozen`, there is another type called `all`. The logic behind it is as follows: `if all > x_frozen { x_frozen = all; }`. `all` applies to all types. It's worth noting that many sections of code use the designation `WithdrawReasons::all()`, which explains why they appear identical most of the time.